# Boost/Py-Boost not being found in Conda Environment while Installing ParallelFDTD

Tags: python, c++, boost, anaconda

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/AaltoRSE/ParallelFDTD) to install ParallelFDTD's python bindings on a windows machine.  I've barely worked with C++ before, and certainly never with Boost!  Mostly have experience with Python.

So far, I have done the following:

1. installed the Windows SDK
2. installed the CUDA toolkit

I have successfully created a conda environment:

```
conda create -n PFDTD -c conda-forge boost py-boost cmake numpy scipy
conda activate PFDTD
```

Running `conda list` shows that `boost 1.73` is installed, along with `py-boost 1.73` and `libboost 1.73` as well as `boost-cpp 1.68`.

So far so good.

When I try to install and build the library as per the instructions with the following, I get an error

```
pip install git+https://github.com/AaltoRSE/ParallelFDTD.git
```

produces:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyParallelFDTD
  Running command python setup.py bdist_wheel
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pyParallelFDTD
  copying dist\libPyFDTD\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pyParallelFDTD
  running build_ext
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0
  -- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.8.89
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8/bin/nvcc.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting CUDA compile features
  -- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
  -- CONDA_PREFIX C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opti-acoustics
  -- Found Python: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/opti-acoustics/python.exe (found version "3.8.13") found components: Interpreter
  -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Python310/libs/python310.lib (found version "3.10.0")
  -- CONDA_PREFIX C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opti-acoustics
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  CMake Error at C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/opti-acoustics/Library/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
    Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system thread date_time
    unit_test_framework python38 chrono numpy38) (Required is at least version
    "1.41")
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/opti-acoustics/Library/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/opti-acoustics/Library/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    CMakeLists.txt:86 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/../AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-3mu877y3/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-38/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/../AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-3mu877y3/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-38/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The key part of the error message seems to be:

```
Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system thread date_time
    unit_test_framework python38 chrono numpy38) (Required is at least version
    "1.41")
```

The instructions suggest that the installation with conda should be sufficient, but it seems some environment variables are missing.  In ParallelFDTD's CMakeLists.txt, you can see how it tries to handle boost installation in a conda env [here](https://github.com/AaltoRSE/ParallelFDTD/blob/aa8037f1f7f4e645d1bbd036cd79761e2c5ea74f/CMakeLists.txt#L48-L91).

It *appears* that `conda install -c conda-forge boost py-boost` installed successfully, for instance there are a lot of `.hpp` files and a `/python` folder as well as a bunch of other directories in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\acoustics_env\library\include\boost`.  There are also a lot of `boost_xxx.dll` files in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\acoustics_env\library\bin`.

So far, I've forked the ParallelFDTD library so that I can make changes to the CMakeLists.txt, including pointing the `BOOST_ROOT`, `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and/or `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR` explicitly to folders in the anaconda env if need be, but I haven't been able to figure out the correct paths to use... I can also try installing boost manually, but just not sure what the best approach is.

Desperate for help!  I'm sure it's a simple step I am missing...

Found lots of other threads that were somewhat related, but none of them seemed to be dealing with this kind of context of working in a conda environment with boost/py-boost.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issues with Boost and Boost.Python for a specific conda library running a specific version of Python (3.11).  I built the Boost.Python library myself.  Everything looks good, but when I then compile a small c++ library that depends on Boost.Python (yes, I set the includes and linker to my own Boost.Python libs) the resulting dll is a scrambled mess.  I've asked questions to the boost-feedstock crew about the proper way to add boost and boost.python to a given conda env.  It isn't easy, and there is NO documentation.  The Boost people should understand that there are dozens of Python configurations out there.  Some people probably have numerous versions of Python on their machine, and each one is particular with respect to the Boost.Python libraries needed to interface with compiled libraries.  In all my decades of writing systems-level code, nothing has been as complex and minimally-documented as the intricacies of building Boost.Python for very specific environments.  If I make any progress with my own installation/build of Boost.Python for a conda environment, I will write it up here.

Comment: As I'm looking at your build output, try this:  create a system environment variable named Boost_INCLUDE_DIR and set its value as the path to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\acoustics_env\library\include\boost   And keep trying things along those lines.  Welcome to Boost Hell.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).